# php,imageresizing

Tags: php, image

```
function rezizecode()
     {   
     $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
     $config['source_image']    = 'system/application/images/manu.jpg';
     $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']= 25;
    $config['height']= 30;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
    $this->image_lib->resize();
     }
```

using this code image resizing  is not working ?

Comment: Please provide the context or at least more explanation. Is that into some sort of framework or what? For sure if you paste that onto a PHP page like that it won't work...

Comment: Its a framework, called Codeigniter, and it has a very well written documentation here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Answer (score 3):

Nobody can answer this question.
this is only smallest part of the code, and it can be not the code at all.

To answer the question "why my code is not working" a programmer must learn to debug, and a user must hire a programmer.

IBM has good article to start on debugging: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

Turn all errors on and try to debug some.

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer. Maybe post in comments next time?

Comment: @Kenaniah Like many other newbies you have no idea of debugging and don't take debugging as an answer. What a pity.

Comment: @Shrapnel, your stupidity is amazing. This technically isn't an answer to the question, and should rather be posted in the comments. Obviously he should learn how to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion :) I see many people who can understand direct answer only. But our life is not that direct...

Answer (score 0):

what environment you are working in, 
What I suspect is the path for the image might incorrect

```
 $config['source_image']    = 'system/application/images/manu.jpg';
```

try to put full path on it.

```
 $config['source_image']    = '[path]/system/application/images/manu.jpg';
```

test it out.